# Concatenate fields with different data types

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to concatenate fields with VarChar and Date into one VarChar field for a database of tourdates.  So, imagine a table of, say, Madonna tour dates as such:

```
TourName           TourStDt          TourEndDt
Like A Virgin      3/5/1985          12/1/1985
Material Girl      1/15/1986         10/10/1987
```

I'm sure the dates aren't accurate, but whatever...  Anyway, so I want to create a query that concatenates the TourName, TourStDt and TourEndDt fields so that it looks like this:

```
Like A Virgin (3/5/1985 to 12/1/1985)
Material Girl (1/15/1986 to 10/10/1987)
```

I wrote a query like this:

```
Select DISTINCT 
    TourID, 
    TourName + '(' + TourStDt + ' to ' + TourEndDt + ')' AS TourName2
from [tblTours] 
ORDER BY [TourID] ASC
```

When I do this, I get an error:

> The data types nvarchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Can anyone tell me how to produce the results I outlined above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the values to strings:

```
Select DISTINCT TourID, 
       TourName + '(' + convert(varchar(255), TourStDt) + ' to ' + convert(varchar(255), TourEndDt) + ')' AS TourName2
from [tblTours] 
ORDER BY [TourID] ASC ;
```

I would suggest that you add a third argument to `convert()` specifying the date format.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thanks!